# AWS Cloudfront SignedURLs length

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

Can anyone tell what the max length of an signed URL from AWS Cloudfront?

This would be important for me since some of my clients can only deal with a certain url length.

Comment: Canned policy or custom policy?

Comment: Im using both policies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally 8,192 bytes is the maximum length for any URL in aws cloudfront.

You can check further limitations here in the given link.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cloudfront-limits.html